# creating html frame moving as the page moves?

Tags: html, css, frames

Html frames are good choice for some scenarios on web content, especially simple content management.

My page contains a top frame and content frame. My problem is, as the page moves down to end, the top should move too, and if scrolling equals top heiht, the top woldn's be seem.

Note: There is only one top page in this project and many content pages. The content pages do not contains also a top page code. Jus the known frameset template. The only difference is frames are desired to move .

Comment: I only understood the first two sentences of that.

Comment: Consider the StackExchange menu, at the top is a top navigation frame.If the page moves, it moves too.

Comment: Both my answer and the other guy's answer will do that for you.

Comment: Are you using `<frame>`s for your site? If so, and if I'm understanding your question, what you're trying to do isn't possible. Try switching to `<iframe>`, that may clear up your issue.

Comment: Please provide further details or close this question. If the answers help you, then consider upping them.

Comment: @TimWasson at this adress, think example5 is up to 50. I don't want to see scrollbar at the left, It must be appear as the page's scrollbar.  [link]http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html

Comment: It is not possible. You'll want to rethink your page structure if this is a project requirement.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri There is no such an answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I could understand is that you tried to create a section of the page that scrolls as you scroll down/up on the page.

In your CSS, if your iframe id is "frame",

then do this

```
#frame{
position:fixed;
/* specify widths and heights as you like */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header that needs to stay at the top of the page use the

```
position: fixed;
```

technique, if im wrong you need to seriously rephrase your question.

Comment: Thank you. Clearly, I want the frames move as the page moves up or down. Not to stay fixed position.

Comment: ya it stays in a fixed position as the page moves